# How do you handle users who don't enable push notifications but might want to later on?

Tags: iphone, push-notification

How do you handle users who initially disable push notifications?  I keep a record of push id's using EASYAPNS and I'm concerned that if someone disables push notifications, they'll miss out on some great features of my app.

What do you do if they want to enable notifications later on?  If I create a settings tab for push notifications and they later on enable them, will the app then and there generate a push id, or is it a one time thing and they're out of luck if they don't register for notifications the first time the app launches?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple's Local and Push Notifications Programming Guide,
"an application should register every time it launches and give its provider the current token.
(...)
Users can thereafter modify the enabled notification types in the Notifications preference of the Settings application, and you can retrieve the currently enabled notification types by calling the `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` method."

The user can always go to the iPhone Settings and enable or disable notifications for your app, doesn't matter if he initially had it enabled or not.

Comment: Cool, thanks for clearing this up, I now know how to implement the features I need.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write the code for setting of Push Notification. iPhone itself has a feature to enable or disable Push Notifications, but application must have implemented the code ofr Push Notification.